# Cassandra Node Capacity Calculation

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am trying to find out what is a data holding capacity of each Cassandra node in a Cluster before it starts showing latency. Basically I need to find out what is the right time to start adding new nodes to the existing cluster. I am referring to [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/capacityPlanning.html#capacityPlanning__estimatingDiskCapacity) page.

We use VMs having single data disk of 100G size. Here is how I calculated the usable disk space for each node.

> raw_capacity = disk_size * number_of_data_disk
>                = 100 G * 1
>                = 100 G
>
> formatted_disk_space = (raw_capacity * 0.9)
>                        = 100 G * 0.9
>                        = 90 G
>
> usable_disk_space = formatted_disk_space * (0.5 to 0.8)
>                     = 90 G * 0.5
>                     = 45 G

So this means each node can hold data upto 45 G. Is this correct understanding?

Also if I need to compare it with current data size, can I directly compare it with nodetool status response? As per above calculation it can hold upto 45 G whereas my cluster is holding only around 11G data. I have been trying to read through, but may be because of my brains, I am not able to understand this.

```
Datacenter: prod_east
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

UN  <IP_1>  11.17 GB   NO TOKENS          ?       <token>  rack1
UN  <IP_2>  12.23 GB   NO TOKENS          ?       <token>  rack1
UN  <IP_3>  10.72 GB   NO TOKENS          ?       <token>  rack1
```

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nodetool status load take in consideration the replication factor, so each node might be having 100% or maybe less, try to add the name if your keyspace as a nodetool status command argument and it will give you the data that each node owns.

Here is an example :

nodetool status your_keyspace_name

Datacenter: dc1

Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                                Rack

UN  127.0.0.1  47.66 MB   1       33.3%   x                                      rack1

UN  127.0.0.2  47.67 MB   1       33.3%   x                                      rack1

UN  127.0.0.3  47.67 MB   1       33.3%   x                                      rack1

Comment: This is based on the ownership of the keys and % is based on the replication factor. My question is about capacity of the node in a cluster. How do we identify if any of the node is reaching its maximum limit and this is the time we need to expand the cluster.

Comment: Basically a node can goes up to 1TB,  then depending on your compaction strategy, you will need between 50% and 20% free space in your disk, I hope that this help.